# What is the best way to delete the application settings when an Outlook add-in is uninstalled?

Tags: outlook, add-in, uninstallation, visual-studio-addins, application-settings

I've written an add-in for Outlook 2010/2007, which I install using a msi installer. During the execution of the add-in I save some settings in MyAddin.Properties.Settings.Default.MySetting. When the settings are saved a new subdirectory is created in %user_home%\Local Settings\Application Data under the Microsoft_Corporation directory.

When I uninstall the add-in the application settings are not deleted. How can I remove this entire directory when the add-in is removed? It is important to me because some of the code depends on the application settings not being set (this is how I know if the code is run for the first time).

Comment: I am also facing this same issue can you help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me this question is not related to Outlook and Addins at all, every "ordinary" application that is installed through a MSI and run by users faces the same problem.

Hence I suggest taking a peek at [How to remove Settings when uninstalling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2698907/how-to-remove-settings-when-uninstalling) . If your situation is somehow different in a way that makes this solution not apply, please explain how it differs so we might be able to help you with a proper solution.

Comment: I guess that the custom action is the way to go :).