# Windows Logo clean uninstall

Tags: windows, installation, settings, uninstallation

Anybody knows a way to cleanly uninstall a program that stores its settings on the per-user basis and installs for all users? I mean only the way to completely following the all Logo (Vista, 7, 8 - Server and Desktop) requirements.

I have found no way but installing a program on per-user basis, which in general can't be the solution.

Maybe leave some `.cmd` files in each user's home folder for cleaning-up application data?

The Logo requirements contains a lot of contradictions, and precisely following them seems to be impossible.

David Walker in his great comment to [What do I do with per-user data when I uninstall?](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/09/17/4948130.aspx#4982424) mentions:

> Some users prefer that an uninstall would do a complete cleanup of all traces of a program.
>
> Other users wish that a later reinstall would not force them to re-customize their settings.
>
> **These two wishes are incompatible**.

Which one Microsoft recommends, actually, to pass all their Logo Certification tests? I mean all of them - from Vista to 8, both Server and Desktop.

Comment: In this case, you usually look at how other software handles such situation. Does Microsoft Office remove all the per-user settings on uninstall?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's Raymond Chen's unofficial [personal recommendation](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/09/17/4948130.aspx).

> No. Let the data go.

Comment: As I have re-read the comments, David Walker's dilemma is the case:

"Some users prefer that an uninstall would do a complete cleanup of all traces of a program.

Other users wish that a later reinstall would not force them to re-customize their settings.

These two wishes are incompatible."

Comment: Thank you for inspiring link! I hope you woun't take offence for my editing of original question...